# How to save another data for Authorization Role in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, plugin, role

Hi Everyone i need help with this case. How can i save   with a plugin with this additional data "Extra Data" ? 
Reference:[image]

How can i add this "extra-data" with the rest of the info of AUthorization Role ?? Please help!

Just in case i've added the column extra_data on the table authorization_role